# How do I turn off comments in embedded youtube video?

Tags: javascript, youtube

I would like to know if possible, how I can turn off youtube video comments that are popping up in the video?

```
var params = { allowScriptAccess: 'always',  wmode : 'transparent' };
var atts = { id: 'myytplayer' };
swfobject.embedSWF('http://www.youtube.com/e/'+OBJ.info['youtubeVideoId']+'?enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer&autohide=1',
                   'ytapiplayer', '447', '251', '8', null, null, params, atts);
```

Comment: all browser? or as much browser as possible